# Is the key generated below valid and cryptographically secure?

Tags: security, ethereumjs, ethers.js, private-key, randomness

For some reason, my React Native 0.68.0 app needs to generate private key for the Ethers wallet providing accessing to `crypto.getRandomValues`. The `crypto.getRandomValues` is polyfilled by [`react-native-get-random-values`](https://github.com/LinusU/react-native-get-random-values/blob/master/index.js). I am not certain if the key generated as such is valid and `cryptographically secure` to serve as ether wallet private key. Any comments would be appreciated. Here is the code:

```
  const uint8Arr = (n) => {. //generate an insecure uint8 array
    let arr = new Uint8Array(n);
    for (let i=0;i<n;i++) {
      let t = Math.floor(Math.random()*256) ;  //0-255
      arr[i] = t;
    };
    return arr;
  };

      //code to generate private key
      let arr8 = uint8Arr(32); //get an insecure uint8 array     
      console.log("uint8 array x 32 : ", arr8);
      global.crypto.getRandomValues(arr8);  //feed the uint8 array above to crypto.getRandomValues for a secure random uint8 array
      console.log("global.crypto.getrandomvalues(32) : ", arr8);
      console.log("ethers.utils.hexlify : ", ethers.utils.hexlify(arr8));  //convert uint8 array to private key in hex format
```

Here is the console output:

```
 LOG  uint8 array x 32 :  [119, 76, 149, 66, 179, 200, 114, 164, 68, 245, 67, 243, 107, 67, 102, 84, 247, 218, 83, 235, 244, 236, 138, 202, 10, 216, 193, 240, 55, 151, 148, 39]
 LOG  global.crypto.getrandomvalues(32) :  [61, 44, 150, 52, 36, 4, 112, 127, 66, 105, 128, 176, 63, 94, 238, 213, 176, 58, 154, 210, 114, 68, 185, 20, 79, 240, 229, 110, 198, 207, 20, 209]
 LOG  ethers.utils.hexlify :  0x3d2c96342404707f426980b03f5eeed5b03a9ad27244b9144ff0e56ec6cf14d1. //<<==private key generated
```

Is the key generated by code above valid and `cryptographically secure` as ether wallet private key?

Comment: Here is an article about react native random generation module security https://www.cossacklabs.com/blog/react-native-libraries-security/. It mentioned weakness of a few popular encryption and random generation modules.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to generate fully random keys with regular hardware. All the keys you generate are pseudo-random - but in most of the cases that's just fine.

Nothing stops you from generating your key analogically. You could for example roll a die enough times to generate a key. I'm not an expert in this, but my guess is that that will give you even worse results, regarding randomness.

In the end, you should trust some code/tool to generate the randomness for you. Yes, it won't be 100% random, but it will be random enough that nobody else has any way to determine the key. That's how 99,99% of keys are formed anyway - some tool somewhere generates the key, and I doubt many keys are cracked based on their lack of randomness. Keys are exposed mostly due to human error.

Comment: It is true that there is hardly a true random implementation programatically. Here the critical piece is the `crypto.getRandomValues` polyfilled by `react-native-get-random-values` which claims cryptographically secure randomness. But with security it seems always have something we don't know now. Trying to avoid known pitfalls.

Comment: Sorry, questions like "how good randomness does a JS function X provide" is a bit out of my league, and not very suited for this community either. You should probably ask in some math/js forum

Answer (score 0):

Using the `crypto.getRandomValues` is cryptographically secure, using `Math.random` **is not** (in general).

In some browsers, `Math.random` uses cryptographically secure sources, but that should not be relied on.

The `crypto.getRandomValues` uses an OS level random source, which is regularly stirred with keystrokes, network packets, BLE noise and these days using hardware RNGs that are usually built into CPUs and secure enclaves.